# Hide Folders in Home directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, home-folder

My Windows 10 user folder:

[image]

I do not want to see Contacts, Favorites and Searches folders within my Home folder. I do not use them and I do not want to see them. Is there a way to hide them or remove them permanently?

I've tried hiding these folder, but it does not work.

[image]

[image]

I've also tried unchecking Readonly checkbox, but that setting will not stick for some reason.

Comment: You can right-click on the items and open `Properties` and then tick `Hidden`. If you have opted not to show hidden files and folders then this will make these directories invisible (unless you show these files). I don't know whether doing this would affect anything else such as program access but I wouldn't imagine so.

Answer (score 1):

Contacts can be hidden using this Registry Edit.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions{56784854-C6CB-462B-8169-88E350ACB882}\PropertyBag]
>   "ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

Comment: And that too only in the users folder namespace view. If the user browses the path by typing in the address bar, it would still show the Contacts folder.

Comment: It seems a logoff/logon is required to see the results.

Comment: Other known folder ID-s can be found in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete them as they are system folders, and they will be recreated upon next boot/login.

You CAN hide them though (assuming you don't have "show hidden files" enabled in Explorer), by simply applying the "hidden" file attribute to them.

To do this:

1. Right-click the folder you want hidden, pick Properties, check-mark "Hidden", and hit OK.

or

2. Open a command prompt, then use `attrib` to hide them. E.G.: `attrib c:\users\YourName\Favorites +h`

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. And it does not work. I can hide other folders in my home directory but not these system directories.